# How to change the ID in pure CSS JS ?Why My code is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is not working, although it seems correct to me. Can you please tell me what's the issue?

```html
<style>
    #101{
        width:1em;
        height:1em;
        padding:1em;
        margin: 1em;
        background-color: green;
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="animation" id="animation">hii</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('animation').id='101';
</script>
```

Comment: It's not recommended that IDs *start* with numbers but that may be unrelated.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732899/8620333

Comment: @GirishSasidharan `101` has three characters and no whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ID in a selector cannot start with a number:

[4.1.3 Characters and case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

You could get around that by writing the selector like this `#\31 01`, but that is not really recommended (`31` is the hexadecimal representation of the character `1`):

```html
<style>
     #\31 01{
        width:1em;
        height:1em;
        padding:1em;
        margin: 1em;
        background-color: green;
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="animation" id="animation">hii</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('animation').id='101';
</script>
```

So it is better to prefix the ID with some letters.

Comment: @TemaniAfif `they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, …`

Comment: ok missed that sentence because In my mind it's valid to start with number since we need to make a difference between the Spec defining the ID inside the HTML doc (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and how to write the selector (the Spec your refering). So it's only invalid to start with a number when writing the selector but it's possible to have number inside the attribute. Many will confuse between both (It was the case for me for a while)

Answer (score 1):

CSS Selectores can't start with a number.

```html
<style>
    #hundred10{
        width:1em;
        height:1em;
        padding:1em;
        margin: 1em;
        background-color: green;
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="animation" id="animation">hii</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('animation').id='hundred10';
</script>
```